# Reverse engineer database in spring data rest

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-data, reverse-engineering

I want to expose CRUD operations to MySql via REST apis. I have just started exploring Spring. I have found Spring rest data to be a good fit for this.

But there is only one problem, automating the generation of java model, repository classes, etc,. What are the tools available that can do this? I want this to be done without any interface, preferably via maven.

Comment: Have a look at Spring Roo and [this](http://www.javabeat.net/spring-roo-spring-data-jpa-eclipse-integration/) tutorial

Comment: @andih Is there any way to automate the spring roo commands?

Comment: Sorry, that I've never tried and thus I can't provide you a useful answer.